# How to calculate capacitance and resistance for this simple A.M. radio?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, radio, math, amplitude-modulation

[image: Envelope Detector]

\$v_i\$ is the A.M. signal, \$v_o\$ is the modulation wave. How do I calculate the optimal capacitance and resistance, for a given carrier wave frequency? If there isn't necessarily an "optimal" configuration,  then how should I go about selecting them? (In actual A.M. radios, how do they tune to different frequencies?)

Here is what I have so far: [falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.0000049999999999999996+11.086722712598132+50+5+50%0A200+176+176+96+176+0+1000+40+5%0Ag+176+256+96+256+0%0Ad+176+176+224+176+1+0.805904783%0Aw+224+256+176+256+0%0Aw+224+176+288+176+0%0Aw+288+256+224+256+0%0Aw+288+176+352+176+0%0Aw+288+256+352+256+0%0Ap+352+176+352+256+0%0Ar+288+176+288+256+0+100%0Ac+224+176+224+256+0+0.00001+0.0008301478447435358%0Ao+0+32+0+550+10+0.2+0+-1%0Ao+8+64+0+550+5+0.00009765625+1+-1%0A)

I have calculus experience, so I could appreciate a mathematical explanation (as opposed to just saying "this is the answer", although that also works).

Comment: Tuning to different frequencies has nothing to do with the schematic fragment here. Here you want the RC product to be much larger than 1/(2*pi) * the period of Vi(t) and smaller than 1/(2*pi) * the period of Vo(t). Simple as that.

Comment: The detector circuit you have shown only becomes an AM radio when it has an antenna. Even with an antenna it's a crappy design.

Comment: You're having a basic confusion here. A different (variable in practice cap) is used for tuning to the carrier frequency even in the simplest designs https://books.google.com/books?id=N9ta5fV7wn0C&pg=PA121

Answer (score 3):

In actual radios, they use the convenient fact that the carrier frequency is much higher than the modulation frequency.  For example, commercial AM goes down to around 550 kHz carrier (don't remember exactly), but the modulation is limited to 10 kHz at most.  That 55:1 ratio gives you a reasonably wide latitude in making a filter that leaves little carrier without cutting into the real signal.

In your circuit, you want the capacitor voltage to decay little between carrier peaks, but still allow for the falling slope of the highest frequency modulation content.  Set the rolloff frequency of the R-C to about the highest modulation frequency of interest.

Comment: 153 kHz carrier on the LW band in Europe.